# Phaser 3 Player Class Not using update() defined in class

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

Still very new to phaser and JavaScript but i am attempting to create several classes that will handle the player, enemies, and coin's, whenever i create the objects their update functions dont seem to ever get called even thoguh my understanding(albeit a poor one) is that they should

Here is my createGooBoi class:

```
export default class createGooBoi extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  constructor(scene, x, y) {
    super(scene, x, y, "GooBoi");
    this.scene.add.existing(this);
    this.setScale(2);
    this.scene.physics.world.enable(this);
    this.scene.add.existing(this);
    this.body.setGravityY(660);
    this.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
  }
  create() {
    console.log("Create GooBoi");
    this.anims.create({
      key: "idle",
      frames: [
        { key: "GooBoi", frame: 0 },
        { key: "GooBoi", frame: 1 },
        { key: "GooBoi", frame: 2 },
        { key: "GooBoi", frame: 3 },
      ],
      frameRate: 8,
      repeat: -1,
    });
  }
  update() {
    console.log("Update GooBoi");
    this.body.play("idle");
  }
}
export default class createGooBoi extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  constructor(scene, x, y) {
    super(scene, x, y, "GooBoi");
    this.scene.add.existing(this);
    this.setScale(2);
    this.scene.physics.world.enable(this);
    this.scene.add.existing(this);
    this.body.setGravityY(660);
    this.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
  }
  create() {
    console.log("Create GooBoi");
    this.anims.create({
      key: "idle",
      frames: [
        { key: "GooBoi", frame: 0 },
        { key: "GooBoi", frame: 1 },
        { key: "GooBoi", frame: 2 },
        { key: "GooBoi", frame: 3 },
      ],
      frameRate: 8,
      repeat: -1,
    });
  }
  update() {
    console.log("Update GooBoi");
    this.body.play("idle");
  }
}
```

And here is my Level_1:

```
import createGooBoi from "../Main/GooBoi.js";
import createHal from "../Main/Hal.js";

//----Varibles----//
var GooBoi_1;
var Coin_1;
var Coin_2;
var Hal;
export class Level_1 extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: "Level_1" });
  }

  create() {
    this.cameras.main.fadeIn(1000, 0, 0, 0);
    //----Level----//
    this.add.image(480, 200, "Level_1_Background");
    var platform = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    var floor = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    //let PlatformSmall_1 = platform.create(300, 300, 'PlatformSmall');
    let PlatformLong_1 = platform.create(475, 250, "PlatformLong");
    PlatformLong_1.setScale(1.5);
    //PlatformSmall_1.setScale(1.2);
    floor.create(480, 440, "Floor").refreshBody();

    //----Hal----//
    this.Hal = new createHal(this, 200, 200);
    Hal;

    //----GooBoi----//
    this.GooBoi_1 = new createGooBoi(this, 500, 200);
    GooBoi_1;

    //----Coin's----//
    this.Coin_1 = new createCoin(this, 500, 400);
    this.Coin_2 = new createCoin(this, 400, 400);
    Coin_1;
    Coin_2;

    //----Collision Mesh----//
    this.physics.add.collider(this.Hal, floor);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.Hal, platform);
  }

  update() {}
}
```

index.html just incase this matters:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Attack of The GooBoi's</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.60.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Game">
      <script type="module">
        import { Boot } from "./scenes/Boot.js";
        import { MainMenu } from "./scenes/MainMenu.js";
        import { Level_1 } from "./scenes/Level_1.js";
        import { Level_2 } from "./scenes/Level_2.js";
        import { Level_3 } from "./scenes/Level_3.js";

        const config = {
          type: Phaser.AUTO,
          width: 960,
          height: 440,
          scene: [Boot, MainMenu, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3],
          pixelArt: true,
          physics: {
            default: "arcade",
            arcade: { debug: true },
          },
        };

        new Phaser.Game(config);
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Not sure where im going wrong but if anyone can explain and help me understand why what im doing doesn't work id much apricate it!

ive attempted to call call the update function of the class within the Level_1 update but that seems to make things angry(there is a good chance im doing that wrong as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well by default, the `update` function is not called. You could cll it yourself in the `update` function of the scene, like this:

```js
//...
// "args" parameter might not be needed
update(...args){
    this.GooBoi_1.update(...args);
    //...
}
```

If you use phaser **Groups** for your sprite, the *automatic* `update`-function can be activated in the groups with the propery `runChildUpdate` and set to `true`.

**Demo for Phaser Groups:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class CustomSprite extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    constructor (scene, x, y) {
        super(scene, x, y);
        this.setTexture('red-box');
        this.setPosition(x, y);
        this.count = 0;
    }

    update (time, delta) {
      this.count++;
    }
}

class Example extends Phaser.Scene {
 
    create ()     {
        this.label = this.add.text(10,10, 'Update-function-call-counter')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

        let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
        graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        graphics.generateTexture('red-box', 10, 10);

     
        this.group = this.add.group({
            defaultKey: 'red-box',
            classType: CustomSprite,
            maxSize: 100,
            // activate update calls
            runChildUpdate: true,
        });


        this.group.create(Phaser.Math.RND.between(50, 200), 0);
        

    
    }

    update () {
        Phaser.Actions.IncY(this.group.getChildren(), 1);
        
        this.label.setText(`Sprite Update calls: ${this.group.getChildren()[0].count}`)

        this.group.children.iterate(child =>
        {
            if (child.y > config.height)
            {
                child.y = 0;
            }
        });
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity: { y: 100 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: Example,
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. I attempted to call the class this way and it’s seemed to not like the reference(I only added a console.log() to attempt isolate if it was the code). But where my confusion is is that I have several scenes that have create() and update() functions that seem to be called and overwrite previous update() or create() is this because it’s and extension of scenes vs sprites? Are these two handled differently in phaser? Finding this information has been a pain and I could just be looking in the wrong places but the documentation doesn’t seem to be super clear.

Comment: Yes, they are handled differently, the Scene `update` functions can be overridden and will be called. The GameObject `update` function can be overridden, but will only be used in Groups/pools as mentioned in the docs _"...To be overridden by custom GameObjects. Allows base objects to be used in a Pool..."_ **btw.:** I think the docs are  pretty good, I use the [offical ](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/index.html) and the [annotated docs ](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/), and the [phaser discourse](https://phaser.discourse.group/) is also very helpful.

Comment: @Khendry **btw.:** if my answer helped with your question, please consider accepting it with the green checkmark under the voting arrows. Thank you in advance.